# Retrieve Addon Version with Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to retrieve the current version of my Firefox addon.

The addon is developed using the Firefox SDK. Currently, my `main.js` file looks like that:

```js
/*=== SDK INIT ===*/

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod"),
    tabs = require("sdk/tabs"),
    data = require("sdk/self").data,
    prefs = require("sdk/simple-prefs"),
    { Cu, Cc, Ci } = require("chrome");

// Get Addon version
let AddonManager = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm").AddonManager;
var version = AddonManager.getAddonByID("< MY_GUID >", function(addon) { return addon.version; });

// [...]
```

where "MY_GUID" is the GUID of my extension. But this does not work at all! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the version through the `self` module

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var version = self.version;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still discovering the Firefox Addon SDK (my bad!). This is a lot simpler than I thought.